# Deduplicating a data frame when the order of values may differ in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(from=c(1, 1, 2, 1), 
                to=c(2, 3, 1, 4), 
                title=c("A", "B", "A", "A"), 
                stringsAsFactors=F)
```

`df` is an object that holds all of the various connections for a network graph. I also have a second `data.frame`, which is the simplified graph data:

```
df2 = data.frame(from=c(1, 1, 3), 
                 to=c(2, 4, 1), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

What I need is to pull the `title` values from `df` into `df2`. I can't simply dedup `df` because a) `from` and `to` can be in different orders, and b) `title` is not unique between connections. The current condition I have is:

```
df2$title = df$title[df2$from == df$from & df2$to == df$to]
```

However, this results in too few rows due to the order of `from` and `to` being reversed in row 2 of `df2`. If I introduce an `OR` condtion, then I get too many results because the connection between 1 and 2 will be matched twice.

My question, then, is how do I effectively "dedup" the `title` variable to append it to `df2`?

The expected outcome is this:

```
   from    to title
1     1     2     A
2     1     4     A
3     3     1     B
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Just added. Sorry about that.

Comment: If it's undirected you should make a standard for yourself that `from < to`. `mutate(from2 = pmin(from, to), to = pmax(from, to), from = from2) %>% select(-from2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr);
merge(mutate(df2, from1 = pmin(from, to), to1 = pmax(from, to)), 
      mutate(df, from1 = pmin(from, to), to1 = pmax(from, to)), 
      by = c("from1", "to1"), all.x = T) %>% 
select(from1, to1, title) %>% unique()

#  from1 to1 title
#1     1   2     A
#3     1   3     B
#4     1   4     A
```

Another way we can try, where `edgeSort` function produce unique edges if the two vertices are the same and use `match` function to match all equal edges.

```
edgeSort <- function(df) apply(df, 1, function(row) paste0(sort(row[1:2]), collapse = ", "))

df2$title <- df$title[match(edgeSort(df2), edgeSort(df))]
df2
  from to title
1    1  2     A
2    1  4     A
3    3  1     B
```

Comment: Close, except that there should be a value for `title` where `from == 3`. I'll add the expected output in my question.

Comment: So the order of `from` and `to` don't matter? for example, `from = 3` and `to = 1` can match `from =1` and `to = 3`?

Comment: Correct. It's data for an undirected graph, so it doesn't matter what order `from` and `to` are in.

Comment: Didn't find a straight forward way to do this. You will need to sort the from and to columns and then `merge` them. And also in the result the order of `from` and `to` are not kept.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it in base R by 2 merge statements:

```
step1 <- merge(df2, df, all.x = TRUE)
step2 <- merge(df2[is.na(step1$title),], df, all.x = TRUE, by.x = c("to", "from"), by.y = c("from", "to")) 
rbind(step1[!is.na(step1$title),], step2)

  from to title
1    1  2     A
2    1  4     A
3    3  1     B
```